# Expand Widget to fill remaining space in ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

As in the image shown above, I want widget 2 to always be at least the height of the remaining space available.

But widget 2 might contain so many ListTiles so that they can not be displayed without scrolling. But scrolling should affect widget 1 and widget 2. What is the best way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `Widget 2` in an `Expanded` Widget.

To scroll both `Widget 1` and `Widget 2`, wrap both of them in a `SingleChildScrollView` Widget.

Comment: This doesn't work because the expanded widget wants to expand infinitely, which causes an exception when placed inside a scrollable widget, as it allows children to expand as much as they want

Comment: Please put your codes here. It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: I can't do that as it is too complex. It also doesn't matter, because my current implementation doesn't work the way I want it to. It is just a workaround, which doesn't work when the screen size is too small.

Comment: It should have worked this way though.

Im thinking that there is something else hindering the correct use of the Expanded Widget, maybe a hardcoded height value.

Answer (score 1):

If you can distinguish between the case with a few and many elements (for example during loading), you can use [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) with [SliverFillRemaining](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverFillRemaining-class.html) for this:

```dart
  var _isLoading = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        _buildWidget1(),
        _buildWidget2(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildWidget1() {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(height: 400, color: Colors.blue),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildWidget2() {
    if(_isLoading) {
      return SliverFillRemaining(
        hasScrollBody: false,
        child: Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );
    } else {
      return SliverFixedExtentList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          _buildItem,
          childCount: childCount,
        ),
        itemExtent: 56,
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: In my use case I had a ListView that occupied a certain portion of the screen, which I wanted to grow to a full height and center its child vertically. ListView was already part of the Column widget so in my case changing it to CustomScrollView with a single child SliverFillRemaining worked.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that would be to place your widgets in Column and wrap it with a single child scroll view. For the ListView use shrinkWrap as true and physics you can set to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics

Here is an example

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap:true,
        physics:NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text("$index"),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
var widgetHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - fixedSize;

return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Container(
    height: widgetHeight,
    child: Widget2
  )
)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?